# Regular expression for @ array

Tags: perl

I'm using one Perl script to prepare Readme text files for my builds. In that script, I used:

```
foreach $line (<LOG>) 
{   
    if(length(trim($line))>0)
    {
    $line=trim($line);
    $line=~ s/[\r]//gs;
    if(rindex($line,'#')!=-1)
    {
    $icut=substr($line,0,index($line,']'));
    $icut2=substr($icut,index($icut,'#')+1,length($icut));
    }
    push(@issue,$icut2);
```

it's fetching correct issue no but when the situation comes like

```
[I#1303350], [I#1270918],[I#1312521] Updated Physical Confirmation Template based on CO
```

then it's fetching only one issue no not all issue i that same line. so i modified my code like

```
foreach $revno(<REV>)
{
    if(length(trim($revno))>0)
    {
        $revno=trim($revno);
        $revno=~ s/[\r]//gs;
        if(rindex($revno,'#')!=-1)
        {
            $revcut=substr($revno,0,rindex($revno,']'));
            print "$revcut\n";
            $revcut1=substr($revcut,index($revcut,'#')+1,length($revcut));
        }
    }
    push(@issue,$revcut1);
```

now it's fetch it all revision no but output is like `1312588,1303350], [I#1270918],[I#1312521` but i want to remove the `#`  `[` `]` `I` only but not `,`

How can I parse this with a regex?

Comment: in short my question is how can i parse the `1312588,1303350], [I#1270918],[I#1312521` to `1312588,1303350,1270918,1312521`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without regular expressions: [Transliterate: tr///](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = '1312588,1303350], [I#1270918],[I#1312521';
$s =~ tr/ ][#I//d;
print "$s\n";
```

Output:

```
1312588,1303350,1270918,1312521
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
echo "[I#1303350], [I#1270918],[I#1312521]" | perl -lnwe "print for m/#(\d+)/g"
```

Comment: That does not preserve commas, as the OP requested.

Comment: So he can pull out the `join` operator and join them.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 my @issues = $line_of_data =~ m/#(\d+)/g;
```

And if you want commas, it's far easier to do this:

```
my $with_commas = join( ', ', @issues );
```

And you still have the individual issues numbers as "atoms" of data.